# NZ_Migrate -status seems incorrect

Tags: netezza

quick question,

One of the arguments for NZ_Migrate is -status which shows you the bytes moved, an average, and time elapsed.

However, I have seen this multiple times now and am witnessing it right now, I am moving a table from our production server to our dev server and the table size is 75GB used, 76GB allocated. I am watching NZ_Migrate scroll right now with status updates and it is still inserting into the table but it is showing a total of 242,580,717,568 moved so far, which is way over the table size. Am I missing something? Does it move something over besides just the table?

Comment: Which -format option are you using in the nz_migrate call?

Answer (score 0):

The data size reported for a table by "used" and "allocated" represent data that has been compressed.

There are two modes of transfer for nz_migrate (-format ascii|binary ) with ascii being the default.

In ascii mode the 75GB of data will be transferred uncompressed, so if we go with the Netezza rule of thumb for compression you might see 75*4 GB actually transferred.

If I run nz_migrate on a sample table (4,839 MB used) local to my system as in binary mode, -stats reports about what you'd expect ( 4,931,452,928 bytes ) right before it ends.

If I do this with ascii mode, status reports well over 11,612,192,768 bytes along the way).

As a side note, if your prod and dev server are the same size then you may greatly benefit from using binary mode.